# R - Average of n observations from the most recent observed date

Tags: r, data-analysis, moving-average

I have a data frame with an ID of individual, Date of observation, and Metric measured. It looks like this:

```
ID  Date    Metric
a   Day 1     9
a   Day 2     8
a   Day 3     9
a   Day 4     8
a   Day 5     7
a   Day 6     6
a   Day 7     5
a   Day 8     4
a   Day 9     3
a   Day 10    3
b   Day 1     6
b   Day 2     7
b   Day 3     6
b   Day 4     7
b   Day 5     8
b   Day 6     9
b   Day 7     9
b   Day 8     9
```

I would like to condense this into a single row on the ID and add variables (prev2, prev3, prev4, prev5) that calculate the average of n observations since the latest observation date (but not including the lastdate in the average). For example - "prev2" is the average of the 2 most recent observations and "prev3" is the average of the 3 most recent observations. So prev2 for ID A is the average of day 8 and day 9 (3.5). prev3 for ID B is the average of day 5, 6, 7 (8.67). Ultimately looking back from the most recent/largest date and average a series of observations.

It should look something like this:

```
ID  lastDate    metric_avg  prev2   prev3   prev4   prev5   
a   Day 10      6.2          3.5     4       4.5      5 
b   Day 8       7.63           9    8.67    8.25    7.8
```

I am trying to create predictor variables to analyze attrition at my company. The thought being that 1 month or 2 months from leaving the job, Johnny's performance metrics change in such a way that could predict if Jimmy is going to attrite in the near future.

Any recommendations or ideas how to analyze this data would be super sweet!

Thanks!

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out what you were getting at, but I think I understand now; If you have a day 6, the the most recent date before that is day 1, does something like prev2 have a value, or would it just be NA because days 4 & 5 are missing (those would be the 2 days before day 6)?

Comment: If there is a day 6, the newly created prev2 variable would be the average of day 4 and 5... If there were only 4 days worth of observations and we tried to find the prev4, the result would be NA. Am I making sense? I also edited the original question to add clarification. - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it using `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `magrittr`.

***Data***

```
df <- 
    data.frame(ID=c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 8), rep("c", 3), "d"),
               Date=c(paste("Day", 1:10), paste("Day", 1:8), paste("Day", 11:13), "Day 8"),
               Metric=c(9, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 3, 1, 8, 10))
```

***Code***

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr); library(magrittr)

df %<>% separate(Date, into=c("d1", "d2")) %>% 
        arrange(ID, as.numeric(d2)) %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        mutate(last_Date=paste("Day", max(as.numeric(d2))), 
               metric_Avg=mean(Metric), 
               prev2=(lag(Metric)+lag(Metric, 2))/2,
               prev3=(lag(Metric)+lag(Metric, 2)+lag(Metric, 3))/3,
               prev4=(lag(Metric)+lag(Metric, 2)+lag(Metric, 3)+lag(Metric, 4))/4,
               prev5=(lag(Metric)+lag(Metric, 2)+lag(Metric, 3)+lag(Metric, 4)+lag(Metric, 5))/5) %>% 
       ungroup %>% 
       filter(last_Date==paste(d1, d2)) %>% 
       select(ID, last_Date, metric_Avg, prev2, prev3, prev4, prev5)

df
```

***Output***

```
  ID     last_Date   metric_Avg   prev2    prev3    prev4   prev5
1  a     Day 10      6.200        3.5      4.000    4.50    5.0
2  b     Day 8       7.625        9.0      8.667    8.25    7.8
3  c     Day 13      4.000        2.0      NA       NA      NA
4  d     Day 8       10.000       NA       NA       NA      NA
```

***Remark***

If your `Date` column has dates then use the `lubridate` package. the first few lines of the code would be:

```
df$Date <- ymd(df$Date) # id the Date is of the form yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy/mm/dd

df %<>% arrange(ID, Date) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(last_Date= max(Date)...
```

Answer (score 0):

"lapply" might be useful:

```
ID <- unique(data$ID)

rowNr <- lapply(ID,function(id){which(data$ID==id)})

lastDate  <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){data$Date[rev(n)[1]]})
metricAvg <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){mean(data$Metric[n])})
prev2     <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){mean(data$Metric[head(tail(c(NA,n),3),2)])})
prev3     <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){mean(data$Metric[head(tail(c(NA,n),4),3)])})
prev4     <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){mean(data$Metric[head(tail(c(NA,n),5),4)])})
prev5     <- lapply(rowNr,function(n){mean(data$Metric[head(tail(c(NA,n),6),5)])})



output <- data.frame( ID         = ID,
                      last_Date  = unlist(lastDate),
                      metric_Avg = unlist(metricAvg),
                      prev2      = unlist(prev2),
                      prev3      = unlist(prev3),
                      prev4      = unlist(prev4),
                      prev5      = unlist(prev5)  )
```

Output:

```
> output
  ID last_Date metric_Avg prev2    prev3 prev4 prev5
1  a    Day 10      6.200   3.5 4.000000  4.50   5.0
2  b     Day 8      7.625   9.0 8.666667  8.25   7.8
```

Another example, that shows what happens if there are not enough days to calculate "prev5", "prev4",...:

```
> data
   ID   Date Metric
1   a  Day 1      9
2   a  Day 2      8
3   a  Day 3      9
4   a  Day 4      8
5   a  Day 5      7
6   a  Day 6      6
7   a  Day 7      5
8   a  Day 8      4
9   a  Day 9      3
10  a Day 10      3
11  b  Day 1      6
12  b  Day 2      7
13  b  Day 3      6
14  b  Day 4      7
15  b  Day 5      8
16  b  Day 6      9
17  b  Day 7      9
18  b  Day 8      9
19  c Day 11      3
20  c Day 12      1
21  c Day 13      8
22  d  Day 8     10
```

Output:

```
> output
  ID last_Date metric_Avg prev2    prev3 prev4 prev5
1  a    Day 10      6.200   3.5 4.000000  4.50   5.0
2  b     Day 8      7.625   9.0 8.666667  8.25   7.8
3  c    Day 13      4.000   2.0       NA    NA    NA
4  d     Day 8     10.000    NA       NA    NA    NA
>
```

This lightweight base R solution is even faster than its overcharged competitor:

```
> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:5000)
+   {
+     ID <- unique(data$ID)
+      .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
  28.28    0.01   28.47 

> #-----------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> library(tidyr); library(dplyr); library(magrittr)

> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:5000)
+   {
+     df <-data
+     
+     df %<>% separate(Date, into=c("d1", "d2")) %>% 
+       arrange(ID, as.numeri .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
  46.56    0.05   46.87 
>
```

Comment: I modified my answer such that the desired NA's appear if there are not enough days.